# functionname.arguments not working in Mozilla

Tags: javascript

I have function works perfect in IE but not in mozilla.

```
function showhide()
{
 alert("test");
 var args=showhide.arguments;
 alert("1"+args);
 for (i=0; i<(args.length); i=i+2) 
 {
  alert("2"+args);
  eval(args[i]+".style.display='"+args[i+1]+"'");
 }
 alert("3"+args);
}
```

I get alert `test` in mozilla but rest of alert does not display.

Comment: You code is pretty bad in multiple ways: 1) You leak a global `i`, 2) You use eval in an inappropriate way. Besides that, consider using a framework like jQuery.

Comment: Ignore advice to use jQuery from people who don't have enough information about the situation to make that recommendation.

Comment: @chetan: Don't use `eval`. It's almost always the wrong solution. Why do you want to use it?

Comment: I assume the arguments come in pairs of IDs and display settings. If so, try `document.getElementById(args[i]).style.display(args[i+1])`

Answer (score 4):

`Function.Arguments` is [depreciated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/arguments), simply use `arguments` on its own;

```
var args = arguments;
```

**Edit**

An alternative to what your doing;

```
function showHide(elementStyles) {
    for (id in elementStyles) {
      alert(id +  " / new style=" + elementStyles[id]);
      document.getElementById(id).style.display = elementStyles[id];
    }
}

showHide({
    myElementId1: "block", 
    myElementId2: "none",
    myElementId3: "inline"
});
```

Or using `arguments`

```
function showHide() {
   for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i += 2) {
      alert(arguments[i] + "/" + arguments[i + 1]);
      ... something other than eval here
   }
}

showHide("myElementId1", "block", "myElementId2", "none");
```

Comment: Still only test print after that i will get errot like uncaught exception: [Exception... "prompt aborted by user" nsresult: "0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)" location: "JS frame :: resource://gre/components/nsPrompter.js :: openTabPrompt :: line 468" data: no]

Answer (score 3):

simply use `arguments` instead of `showhide.arguments`